# SQL Query with killing duplicate values

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT first.name,first.country, second.name, second.string
FROM 
first LEFT OUTER JOIN second
ON 
first.name = second.name 
WHERE 
first.date='2015/02/24'
```

This query means all record from second table and matching record from first table. Now my question is that on 24 Feb 2015 I have duplicate names in second table and I want distinct names from second table and then its matching values from first table. Now my query is showing all duplicate values from second table and its matching record from first table. Any help in this regard. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you just add "distinct"?

Comment: The query means `All records from the First Table` not second table, only match rows from the second table, goole `ROW_NUMBER()` to get distinct values.

Comment: ohh yaa exactly first is on left side. You are absolutely right. But I want names from second table distinct not duplicate and their matching records from first table.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your query gets **all** rows from the **first** table (with date '2015/02/24') and **matching** records from the **second** table.

Hopefully your table has a primary key (column `id` in the example). Then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT first.name,first.country, second.name, second.string
    FROM 
        first
    LEFT OUTER JOIN second
    ON 
    second.id = (SELECT min(id) FROM second_min WHERE first.name = second_min.name)
    WHERE 
        first.date='2015/02/24'
```